# Google map in tcpdf not showing correct path

Tags: tcpdf, google-maps-static-api

Below is the static url I am using in [`tcpdf`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html):

> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=800x800&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green|label:A|52.3693824,4.8871682&markers=color:green|label:B|52.369369,4.901235&markers=color:red|label:C|52.3585252,4.8808168&path=color:66ACF2|weight:3|enc:uks~Haoy\iDOCp@Ap@pGVV?@o@B_Db@MXSCsDrBaDN[S_@S_@?Mn@}I?uDIu@@aBBw@@o@LoCHmA?s@AoDI_CA_AJ{FH{BD]h@kBT_AJSLKRIZMFAEm@m@oDG[U[wBeCuBcCIMI]GgACWG?I?GCQUGGG@SUGAK@}@tCiBhGs@dC[z@QTQJe@L{ALoHb@M?K~@WrAEHNNt@l@jB|AvFrFhAbAfAfAnBjB~@|@LDJBRj@tAxE^rAt@jCPn@VAn@BZLf@T@F~Dn@RLVLtCn@nD|@ZADCvBj@zBj@AV_BbUbB|A~BrBjAdAz@d@RPx@pAm@bBo@|A[z@?H?B?@M\vAnItGr_@HTx@i@z@g@zByAHIHEAWo@wD_AmF&sensor=false

I think due to the encryted path, tcpdf is not parsing this and showing wrong path in google maps.

Can someone help me regarding this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`writeHTMLCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246) & `<img>` html tag:

```php
$html = <<<EOD
    <img border="0" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=800x800&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green|label:A|52.3693824,4.8871682&markers=color:green|label:B|52.369369,4.901235&markers=color:red|label:C|52.3585252,4.8808168&path=color:66ACF2|weight:3|enc:uks~Haoy\iDOCp@Ap@pGVV?@o@B_Db@MXSCsDrBaDN[S_@S_@?Mn@}I?uDIu@@aBBw@@o@LoCHmA?s@AoDI_CA_AJ{FH{BD]h@kBT_AJSLKRIZMFAEm@m@oDG[U[wBeCuBcCIMI]GgACWG?I?GCQUGGG@SUGAK@}@tCiBhGs@dC[z@QTQJe@L{ALoHb@M?K~@WrAEHNNt@l@jB|AvFrFhAbAfAfAnBjB~@|@LDJBRj@tAxE^rAt@jCPn@VAn@BZLf@T@F~Dn@RLVLtCn@nD|@ZADCvBj@zBj@AV_BbUbB|A~BrBjAdAz@d@RPx@pAm@bBo@|A[z@?H?B?@M\vAnItGr_@HTx@i@z@g@zByAHIHEAWo@wD_AmF&sensor=false" alt="Greenwich, England">
EOD;
$pdf->writeHTMLCell('', '', 0, 0, $html, 0, 1, false, true, 'L', false);
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**
You also can use [`Image()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352):

```php
$pdf->Image(
    'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=14&size=800x800&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green|label:A|52.3693824,4.8871682&markers=color:green|label:B|52.369369,4.901235&markers=color:red|label:C|52.3585252,4.8808168&path=color:66ACF2|weight:3|enc:uks~Haoy\iDOCp@Ap@pGVV?@o@B_Db@MXSCsDrBaDN[S_@S_@?Mn@}I?uDIu@@aBBw@@o@LoCHmA?s@AoDI_CA_AJ{FH{BD]h@kBT_AJSLKRIZMFAEm@m@oDG[U[wBeCuBcCIMI]GgACWG?I?GCQUGGG@SUGAK@}@tCiBhGs@dC[z@QTQJe@L{ALoHb@M?K~@WrAEHNNt@l@jB|AvFrFhAbAfAfAnBjB~@|@LDJBRj@tAxE^rAt@jCPn@VAn@BZLf@T@F~Dn@RLVLtCn@nD|@ZADCvBj@zBj@AV_BbUbB|A~BrBjAdAz@d@RPx@pAm@bBo@|A[z@?H?B?@M\vAnItGr_@HTx@i@z@g@zByAHIHEAWo@wD_AmF&sensor=false', 
    0.5, 0.5, 20, 20, '', '', '', false, 300
);
```

It show path line correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But i tried using writeHTMLCell as you mentioned. I did not generate the correct path in google map. Also in your above example bmp , there is only location markers but no route path. If you directly put the google map url in browser, then you can see the route path too, but it is missing in your example and at my end it is showing wrong path. Please check. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2940248 Updated;

Comment: In either case, I'd recommend you URL-encode the path, to make sure the HTTP request going out is valid and thus works well all the time.